# Motores de buscas priorizam nomes de arquivos ou atributos "alt" em imagens?

Tags: html, seo

Por exemplo, uma imagem nomeada de `"xicara-de-cafe.jpg"` sem o atributo `alt`, tem mais peso que um arquivo chamado `"5ecaac15bb162ea847e1f4771a214b74.jpg"` com o atributo `alt="Xícara de café"`?

Respectivamente:

```
<img src="/uploads/xicara-de-cafe.jpg" />

<img src="/uploads/5ecaac15bb162ea847e1f4771a214b74.jpg" alt="Xícara de Café" />
```

Qual dos dois códigos será indexado melhor pelos motores de busca?

> Apenas por curiosidade, o segundo nome de arquivo é o hash MD5 do primeiro.

Comment: O melhor seria utilizar os dois: ter o nome da imagem e o texto descritivo em `alt` (e possivelmente o título também). Agora, qual deles tem mais peso, acho difícil dizer. Provavelmente o atributo `alt` tenha mais peso por se tratar de um texto corrido, o que geralmente representa mais informações que um nome de arquivo consegue. O atributo [`longdesc`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-longdesc/) também entraria linha.

Comment: Eu discordo, eles vão buscar o nome do arquivo, o `alt` é uma alternativa descritiva de uma imagem, quando ela não está disponível...(Posso estar errado)

Comment: Eu compreendo que o uso dos dois seja o melhor, porém vamos supor que preciso escolher entre um ou outro. Qual seria melhor? A dúvida surgiu devido a necessidade de tratar nomes de imagens de um sistema de blog. Algumas imagens estão sendo enviadas com nomes muito longos, porém todas contém um atributo alt adequado. Por isso pensei em deixar todos os nomes com MD5 e manter o atributo alt.

Comment: Acho que não há problemas nisso, não. Site da [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016?hl=pt) também indica a utilização dos dois, então acredito que será melhor achar uma alternativa para isso. Também cita a utilização de [sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636) para auxiliar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O algoritmo de indexação dos buscadores dá um peso para cada item e outro peso pela combinação de itens. O melhor seria ter os dois. O nome do arquivo objetivo e o alt mais completo. Se tivesse que escolher, seria de acordo com o comprimento do texto. Mais curto no título, mais longo no ALT.